# Add missing periods in Python

Tags: python

I have the next list of sentences:

```
list_of_sentense = ['Hi how are you?', 'I am good', 'Great!', 'I am doing good,', 'Good.']
```

I want to convert it into:

```
['Hi how are you?', 'I am good.', 'Great!', 'I am doing good.', 'Good.']
```

So I need to insert a period only if a sentence doesn't end with '?', '!' or '.'. Also if a sentence ends with a comma I need to change it into a period.

My code is here:

```
list_of_sentense_fixed = []
for i in range(len(list_of_sentense)):
    b = list_of_sentense[i]
    b = b + '.' if (not b.endswith('.')) or (not b.endswith('!')) or (not b.endswith('?')) else b
    list_of_sentense_fixed.append(b)
```

But it doesn't work properly.

Comment: "But it doesn't work properly" is not a very detailed bug report :-) Perhaps you could elaborate a little.

Comment: Note that when a string ends with ``.``, it cannot ends with ``!``. Same for any other combination of accepted endings. There can never be more than one of your conditions returning False, and ``or`` requires *all* of them to return False.

Answer (score 2):

Just define a function to fix *one* sentence, then use list comprehension to construct a new list from the old:

```
def fix_sentence(str):
    if str == "":                    # Don't change empty strings.
        return str
    if str[-1] in ["?", ".", "!"]:   # Don't change if already okay.
        return str
    if str[-1] == ",":               # Change trailing ',' to '.'.
        return str[:-1] + "."
    return str + "."                 # Otherwise, add '.'.

orig_sentences = ['Hi how are you?', 'I am good', 'Great!', 'I am doing good,', 'Good.']
fixed_sentences = [fix_sentence(item) for item in orig_sentences]
print(fixed_sentences)
```

This outputs, as requested:

```
['Hi how are you?', 'I am good.', 'Great!', 'I am doing good.', 'Good.']
```

With a separate function, you can just improve `fix_sentence()` if/when new rules need to be added.

For example, being able to handle empty strings so that you don't get an exception when trying to extract the last character from them, as per the first two lines of the function.

Comment: Same as in @Maroun's answer. What happends if one of the strings is `''`? I'd stick to `endswith()`

Comment: @Simon, looks like I fixed that bug 30 seconds before you raised it :-) And yes, you could also use `endswith()`, but it complicates the `if char in <collection>` line, so I think I'll stick with what I've got.

Answer (score 1):

According to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you should change to:

```
b = b + '.' if (not b.endswith('.')) and (not b.endswith('!')) and (not b.endswith('?')) else b
```

You can simplify to:

```
b = b + '.' if b and b[-1] not in ('.', '!', '?') else b
```

Comment: What happens, if there is an empty string within the array?

Comment: @SimonFink Good point. That's an edge case that should be addressed. I edited my answer.

Comment: You also missed out on the comma-to-period requirement. That's understandable since OPs *code* didn't have it, but it's definitely in the *text.*